# Mongoose-fuzzy-searching returns empty array unless query is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, plugins, fuzzy-search

I am working on a wiki-like website component and I am trying to implement a fuzzy search. I found a popular Node.js plugin on npmjs for a fuzzy search of a cloud mongoDB database handled with Mongoose. I installed and saved mongoose-fuzzy-searching and hooked it up to my model and route. Then I updated all of the models, resaving each's value for the field I wanted to index. I can seem to call the function on a model, and it seems like there's an index on MongoDB Atlas, but it returns an empty array instead of any results. 2 questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong, or is there something I am missing?
2. Is there a better node library that's *free*? (*Free on heroku, which I think eliminates flexsearch as an option)

Here's my code.

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    mongoose_fuzzy_searching = require('mongoose-fuzzy-searching'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const IssueTemplateSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    info: String,
    image: String,
    tags: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tag"}],
    active: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    instances: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "LocalIssue"}],
    issues: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Issuegraph" },
});

IssueTemplateSchema.plugin(mongoose_fuzzy_searching, { fields: ['name'] });
module.exports = mongoose.model("IssueTemplate", IssueTemplateSchema);
```

An update to all of the issuetemplate models:

```
const   express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    Issue = require('../api/issue/issue.template');

router.get("/createIndex", async (req, res) => {
    Issue.find({}, async (err, issues) => {
        if(err){console.log(err)}else {
            for(issue of issues){
                if(err){console.log(err)}else{
                    const name = issue.name;
                    await Issue.findByIdAndUpdate(issue._id, {name: name}, {strict: false});
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return res.send("done");
});
```

Route:

```
router.get("/search", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.target);
    let searchTerm = "";
    if(req.query.target){
        searchTerm = decodeURIComponent(req.query.target.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
    Issue.fuzzySearch(searchTerm, (err, issue)=> {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send("Error fuzzy searching: " + err);
        } else {
            returnResult(issue);
        }
    });
    
    function returnResult(result) {
        console.log(result);
        return res.send(result);
    }
});
```

When I ran

```
npm install --save mongoose-fuzzy-searching
```

I received an error saying it needed mongoose 5.10, and I have 5.11, but it seemed to at least plug in. Can't see why  When I send a request through Postman, I receive an empty array. If I leave the query blank, then I get everything. I have reset Node and am using mongoDB Cloud, where I see an index has been created. Is there perhaps a reset of the cloud database I would need to do (I don't know of such a thing), or is resetting the server enough? My knowledge level is: studying to be a freelance web developer and would appreciate any general tips on best practice, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose need to define schema. which makes it slow and `find()` method is good for development, not for production level. Also ,This Process is outdated. You are working on `MongoDB`. if you need search  then take a look into MongoDB atlas Full Text-Search.It includes all of those searching features like: `autocomplete`, `Fuzzy Search` everything.

Comment: The Atlas built-in search looked exciting, but it's not accessible to the free tier unfortunately, which eliminates it for my purposes. Aside from that, what process exactly is outdated and what is it replaced by?

Comment: NO, Atlas full text search is available in free tier. Many developers still use it in free tier. Checkout carefully.. Infact everything is free in free tier... and you are also getting 1M/ Request from your searches in your searches from `Mongodb Realm`.    `Mongoose` is outdated and its working is extremely slow for a bigger dataset.

Comment: Try to use Mongodb Atlas search see this: https://youtu.be/4QUGWnz-XaA

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my update operation was not actually updating the field I wanted to update, because `findByIdAndUpdate()` returns a **query** and I wasn't executing that query (with `.exec()` ). Await was also being used incorrectly because its purpose is not just to pause in an async function like I thought, but to wait for a promise to fulfill. A query is not a promise, and await is specifically for promises. Before I learned these details, I solved my problem in another way by using `.find()` , then `.markModified("name")` , then `.save()` . Once I did that, it all worked!